# PFImageView not displaying on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I am having trouble with Parse's PFImageView in an iOS app.

I have a custom UITableViewCell of class MainProfileTableViewCell that is in a UITableView. This UITableViewCell has a UIImageView property called profilePicture. Basically what I am trying to do is use Parse's PFImageView, have it download the current user's profile picture, and then have the UITableViewCell's profilePicture be the PFImageView (I am using storyboards).

The issue is that when I run the app and go to the UITableView were all this is happening, there is nothing there where the profile picture should be. Any help?

(By the way, this UITableView has only one cell right now, which is the custom UITableViewCell.)

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MainProfileTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mainProfile" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    PFImageView *profileImage = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
    profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lincoln"];
    profileImage.file = currentUser[@"profilePicture"];
    [profileImage loadInBackground];

    cell.profilePicture = profileImage;
    cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:cell.profilePicture];

    return cell;
}
```

Other useful information:
The UIImageView profileImage is connected to the UIImageView in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it: added

```
        profileImage.frame = cell.profilePicture.frame;
```

before calling the loadInBackground method.

Comment: The new issue is that the image isn't rounded and circular despite:  cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = YES;